# Menu does not close when clicking again on open menu title

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on some code I did not write, a C# app using Windows Forms, with with I am not very familiar.  The app has a main menu (a contextMenuStrip in Designer) which opens when you click it, but if you click it again on the menu name, it does not close. It flashes, like it is closing and immediately re-opening.  Actually - it closes as long as the mouse is down, but then on Mouse UP it opens again.

EDIT:  Ok so I see what it is doing, just not sure how to fix it.  The menu "header" is a label with an event attached to "click" which opens the menu.  So, clicking the title opens the menu.  But then clicking it again also opens the menu.  I don't think I can check the state of the form, though, because on the second click, the menu closes on mouseDown, so it's already closed by the time the 'click' happens on mouseUp...

In other words, when the menu is open, pressing down on the header causes the menu to close -- I guess because the default behavior for a menu is to close when you click somewhere else.  So the menu closes, but then when the user lifts his finger, the Click even fires again and the menu re-opens.   So how to work around that?

```
private void labelMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((EcPaMainForm)Owner).vShowMainMenu(labelMainMenu);
}

public void vShowMainMenu(Control oButton)
    {
        contextMenuStripMain.Show(oButton.Parent, (oButton.Right+oButton.Left)/2, oButton.Bottom);
    }
```

Comment: We need the code that produces that for us.

Comment: Has it ever worked? I guess it has, as someone else wrote the code.

What has changed since it did work?  
Why I answer the question in this skewed fashion is that I don't believe it is the menu code that is wrong but something else that has triggered this behaviour.

Does it work through keyboard shortcuts?

(If you have happened to send it to the customer you might tell them about keyboard navigation to give yourself a little more time.)

Comment: I don't think it has ever worked.  I just updated my Q with more details...

Comment: Again, post code for this issue.  That's how we help people around here.

Comment: Well, I mean there's not much code.  Just a call to open the menu on the click event.  I put it up there.  It's pretty clear what is happening, isn't it?  I just don't know the better way to do it.

Comment: We need to see what's going on in the vShowMainMenu method you posted.  The code you have posted so far does not reproduce the behavior.

Comment: OK I put that up there.

Comment: The menu is supposed to do that.  This is how things work.  The menu captures the mouse information looking for a mouse down in order to close it.  It does, but since you are clicking on the label, it shows it again.

Comment: Most programs will close the menu if you click on the menu title when the menu is open.  That's what I am trying to figure out how to make this thing do.